# How can I limit search results to only one child site below the current site?

Tags: 2013, search, search-query

I have an application where the end user is able to add new subsites to existing sites, and add sub sites to those sub sites and so on. As part of the site template I have a Search Results Web Part which is supposed to return a list of sites (and information from a custom SiteInformation list located on that site) one level below the current one i.e. show the site information for this sites immediate children.

Unfortunately using a simple query like

```
Path:"{\Site.URL}" ContentTypeID:MySiteInfoContentType
```

shows results from every site below the current site including all child and sub sites.

How can I restrict the search to only return results from one level of sub sites down?

I've been trying to do this using a wildcard search with space for one level of child site i.e.

```
Path:"{\Site.URL}" + "/*/Lists/SiteInformation/DispForm.aspx"
```

But it's not getting me anywhere. Is there a better way to limit search results by depth of sub site? For example is there a Site Parent variable which I could use?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the property `UrlDepth`.  It allows you to manipulate [how deep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn169052.aspx#sp15_example_2_ranking) the URL needs to go for the query. for example;

```
UrlDepth=1 returns things like http://site/subsite
UrlDepth=2 returns things like http://site/pages/page.aspx or http://site/subsite/subsite
```

May help a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2013 probably the easiest way to restrict search query to a specific web would be to specify `WebId` property:

```
WebId:"Web Id goes here"
```

**Example**

[image]

### How to determine WebId property for a web site

The following REST query returns `SP.Web.ID` property:

```
https://[site collection]/[web]/_api/web?$select=Id
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim - this is useful but I don't think it helps in my specific case. I need to return results only from the direct child sites of the site I'm on. I was hoping here would be a property like parent so I could search for Parent:Site.Url or something along those lines.

Comment: Tim, AFAIK there is no way to restrict search query to sub site (direct child) that way

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me;

```
path:"https://contoso/sites/programs" UrlDepth=3 contentclass:STS_Web Site<>{Site.URL}﻿
```

with some trickery from ShareGate team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAaYKe9HaDU

Answer (score 0):

As Matt says, you can you the **UrlDepth** param, however, remember to use it right after the **path** param, in order to make it work accordingly.

Here is an example, that will return only the 1st level child sites of a given site:

```
path:{site url} UrlDepth:3 contentclass:STS_Web
```